# How do you go about using 'lib' folders in .Net projects for building in dependencies?

Tags: c#, .net, svn, continuous-integration

I need to get my external dll dependencies (automap, others ...) into a situation where I can build them on my build server. I would also like to get then them into subversion, so the build server can pick them up.

So I'm new to the whole 'lib' folder thing. I've searched Google, but it seems it's kind of assumed, there are no basics of what to do here. The books I own don't go into it. It's been a long time since I had a mentor at work, or even someone I could ask questions of ... and I'd really love to understand the fundamentals of what I should be doing here.

I write in .Net, use Jenkins as my CI server (new to that) and msbuild (new to that too). I'm hearing svn:externals (don't compute), NuGet ....

Please help!

Comment: Not really sure what the question is.  Are you looking to duplicate the typical "lib" directory in OSS projects?  Just create a lib directory at the same level as your source (or src) directory and copy the assemblies in to there.  Check that in to SVN so that your CI can see them.  Otherwise, just use Nuget, you don't need a "lib" directory if you use nuget and your CI server should "just work"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose my solution is called MySolution and is stored in C:\MySolution, then I have have three directories for binaries, all managed by source control.

- **vendor** the source code of third party frameworks. If needed they are built and signed (with my key) and treated as if the code was my own. This is sometimes necessary to "fix" defects in the framework or debug their source to understand why it fails.
- **src\packages** modules managed by nuget (I wished to combine this with my "lib" folder, but that isn't yet supported)
- **lib** compiled libraries for which I don't have the source and that are not managed by nuget.

(I have omitted folders like "src", "sample", "setup", "documentation" and "scripts" to keep the answer specific to the OP).

The recent months I started to create my own nuget packages for "packages" in the lib folder so I can migrate all of them to "packages".  Its published to a private nuget server.  It also simplify managing the binaries across solutions.

I use to use externs, but they pose a branching nightmare after a while because you have to branch and pin the external dependencies to.  With nuget this is no longer needed.

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely avoid putting binaries in source control. You'd be far better off creating your own nuget repository containing your preferred versions of packages and either using nuget restore or some other way of "rehydrating" your dependencies for building. I use a simple batch file called nuget-update.bat which just looks at all packages.config files and gets any dependencies it finds.

Comment: So would I have to setup a local repository on my PC, and on the build server in the same location? For example, I'd have C:\LocalPackageRepo on both machines?

Comment: This advise poses challenges when you start to branch and have to maintain several versions of released products that each use their own versions of those assemblies.

Comment: My team and I use a versioning system and package all our internal dependencies and it works just fine for us. We have a package server hosted within IIS which is accessible by our development machines and our build server.

Comment: I did the same thing. But had some challenges when trying to match the versions between nuget and the numerous branches.  Some of my binaries however isn't suited for nuget as it relies on COM and native code.

Comment: We use semver for everything and have a build step which automatically updates the version based on tags in the (kiln) repository. So, we don't have any issues with branches.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you posted a sequence of questions on the same topic. I recommend NuGet, as it becomes critical and promoted hard by Microsoft. However, many old libraries are not available there, and you may still need to keep a lib folder. My open source project #SNMP is a good example,

I tried to use as many NuGet packages as possible, and even stepped up to maintain some of the dependencies, such as DockPanel Suite.